# How do I dynamically change the source of an Iframe using Razor and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, razor

I'm having trouble changing the source of an Iframe when a link is clicked.  I've only been working with Razor, Jquery, and Javascript for about two weeks.  My goal is to take the current URL of the link and change the GUID and set the Iframe source to my new URL.

This is what my Iframe looks like:

```
<iframe name="main" id="mainIframe" src="about:blank" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

My menu items:

```
<a id="menuitem" href="#" data-url="@menuItem.Url">@menuItem.Name</a>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('#menuitem').click(function () {
    var url= $(this).data('url');
    firstPart = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('&') + 1);
    $('#mainIframe').attr('src', firstPart + generateGUID());
});
```

Currently, the Iframe is not loading my specified URL and I don't know how to debug Javascript very well.  Can someone look through my code snippets and make sure there isn't something drastically wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

What does generatedGUID() ? and how looks like the "@menuIteam.Url" ?

Comment: generateGUID() creates and returns a new GUID, and @menuItem.Url is a url that ends with XMLGUID&= followed by the current GUID which will be replaced